# I want to move my SKLabelNode object in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have designed a SKLabelNode object. I want to let it move start from down to up and then up to down whenever I touch the SKLabelNode object. First it will move from down to up and then it is required to move from up to down. Here is the code.. Can anyone help !

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //SKNode *helloNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"helloNode"];

    SKNode * helloNode=[self childNodeWithName:@"helloNode"];
    if ([helloNode.name isEqualToString:@"helloNode"])
    {
        helloNode.name = @"";
        SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX: 0 y: 100.0 duration: 0.5];
        //SKAction *zoom = [SKAction scaleTo: 2.0 duration: 0.25];
        SKAction *pause = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.5];
        SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration: 0.25];
        SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.25];

        //SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *moveSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, pause, fadeAway,fadeIn]];
        [helloNode runAction: moveSequence];
    }
    else
    {
        helloNode.name=@"helloNode";
        SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveByX: 0 y: 50.0 duration: 0.5];
        //SKAction *zoom = [SKAction scaleTo: 2.0 duration: 0.25];
        SKAction *pause = [SKAction waitForDuration: 0.5];
        SKAction *fadeAway = [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration: 0.25];
        SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.25];

        //SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        SKAction *moveSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveUp, pause, fadeAway,fadeIn]];
        [helloNode runAction: moveSequence];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact problem
you are facing.

You can start the move upwards action in your didMoveToView or wherever you want. After that you simply run your move downwards action in your touch listener.

If you want to toggle your move direction (one time up, next time
down..) you need to remove the previous action before you set the new one or just overwrite it (use the same action name).